# How can i console origin value using node?

Tags: node.js, console, special-characters

When i try to print a special string, I get messy code:

```js
const str = "\xa7\xe6\xd9\xe6\x95\xe6\xe4\xb0\x82L\x13"
console.log(str) // §æÙææä°L
// expect: the origin value, "\xa7\xe6\xd9\xe6\x95\xe6\xe4\xb0\x82L\x13".
```

It seems the terminal will encode string using utf8 automatically.

How can i print or get the origin input: `"\xa7\xe6\xd9\xe6\x95\xe6\xe4\xb0\x82L\x13"` when i use node ?

Comment: `const str = "\\xa7\\xe6\\xd9\\xe6\\x95\\xe6\\xe4\\xb0\\x82L\\x13"`

Comment: Is the `L` near the end a mistake or is it meant to be there?

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

```
const str = String.raw`\xa7\xe6\xd9\xe6\x95\xe6\xe4\xb0\x82L\x13`;
console.log(str); // \xa7\xe6\xd9\xe6\x95\xe6\xe4\xb0\x82L\x13
```

If you were printing out a string variable, Javascript (for the sake of brevity I will use just your first "character" to illustrate) will never print something like `\xa7` as the visual rendition for a character. This is because the character with a code value of 0xA7 (see second last paragraph below) prints out perfectly fine with a well-defined glyph `§` that is compatible with most output devices (unlike something like `\x07` BEL).

Note that a string literal such as `"\xa7"` is NOT a or one byte. A JS string is encoded in [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), so each character is either 2 bytes, or 4 bytes (for those that require surrogates). The character with codepoint value equal to 0xA7 ([SECTION SIGN U+00A7](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a7/index.htm)) in a JS string has the notation `\u{00a7}` (and not `\xa7`), which, when printed, is rendered `§`.

If you assign a literal value of `\xa7` to a variable, I think JS treats it as two bytes: 0x00 and 0xA7 (the order depending on the endianess), thus forming the UTF-16 encoding of codepoint U+00A7.

In order to understand and answer your question correctly, you should give some clarification on the origins of that "special string" you presented.